# Genymotion - connect to Rest services

Tags: android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, genymotion

I am building a hybrid app in Ionic. In order to test some camera features, I am trying to use Genymotion.

After I start the Genymotion virtual device, I execute the below command from terminal to emulate the application in Genymotion

> ionic run android

This shows a BUILD SUCCESSFUL message and I can see the login page of my mobile app in Genymotion. However, when I click on the login button nothing happens. The login button calls a Rest service (deployed on tomcat) using $http.get(..)

When I checked the Tomcat logs, I found that the rest calls are not reaching Tomcat REST services.

I can't make out what could be preventing the call to REST services from within Genymotion.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Comment: try using your or Genymotion VBox IP Address instead of localhost like...

if you url is like "http://localhost/myProjectFolder/myApi/v1/apiName"
then change it to "http://192.168.56.1/myProjectFolder/..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are pointing to the right IP.

You can't use localhost (as this would be the emulator itself) and not the local ip. You will need to point to the host by using `10.0.3.2` (if you haven't changed it otherwise).